How to create a Q-Toolbar that becomes sticky on the top when user scrolls down?
I'm building a VueJS-Application using QuasarFramework that has a QToolbar inside a QHeader, so that the toolbar stays always on top.
Now I want to put the Toolbar little lower to have another component on the very top. Both should be able to scroll up when the user scrolls down. However, then the user scrolls down more then 60px, the toolbar shall be rendered on top again and become sticky.
I figured out, that the QHeader-component aleady has a reveal-property. Set to true, it makes the Tool visible when the user scrolls up and hides it, when the user scrolls down.  I want to have the opposite behaviour.
So I tried to make the reveal-property dependent on some scrolling behaviour. But this doesn't work because the scoll-event will never be triggered.
How can I achieve the wanted behaviour?
Here is the main-layout:
<template>
  <q-layout view="hHh lpR fFf" no-shadow class="no-shadow">
      <ToolBarComponent :reveal="revealHeader"></ToolBarComponent>

      <q-drawer side="right" bordered v-model="rightDrawerOpen">
        <SideBarComponent/>
      </q-drawer>

      <q-page-container @scroll="handleScroll" class="scrollable-content">
        <DisclaimerBarComponent/>
        <router-view/>
      </q-page-container>

      <GDPRBannerComponent></GDPRBannerComponent>
      <FooterComponent></FooterComponent>
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'MainLayout',

      mounted() {
        const scrollableContent = this.$el.querySelector('.scrollable-content');
        if (scrollableContent) {
          scrollableContent.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        }
      },
    
      beforeUnmount() {
        const scrollableContent = this.$el.querySelector('.scrollable-content');
        if (scrollableContent) {
          scrollableContent.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        }
      },

      setup() {
        const lastScrollPosition = ref(0);
        const revealHeader = ref(false);
    
        const handleScroll = (event: any) => {
          const currentScrollPosition = event.target.scrollTop;
          console.log('Scroll', currentScrollPosition, lastScrollPosition.value)
          revealHeader.value = currentScrollPosition > lastScrollPosition.value;
          lastScrollPosition.value = currentScrollPosition;
        };
    
      }
    )}


</script>

ToolbarComponent.vue:
<template>
  <q-header elevated ref="header" :reveal="revealHeader">
    <q-toolbar class="bg-black toolbar">
      <q-toolbar-title>
          ...
      </q-toolbar-title>
      ...
      <q-btn dense flat round icon="menu" @click="toggleRightDrawer"/>
    </q-toolbar>
  </q-header>
</template>

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ToolBarComponent',

  props: {
    revealHeader: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },

  ...
}

